# MYSQL - Show results only if both tables have entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:  `Tracking`, and `Files`.

- Tracking contains lots of fields with track_id as the primary key.
- Files contains a file_id, track_id, filename, and approved.

The `track_id` is obviously linking the files record back to the tracking record.  The can be multiple files records for the same track_id

What I need to do is to display a list of all records in tracking, that have files that have not been approved.

Right now for testing, I have one tracking record that has 3 files associated with it.  My thought process was to use Left Join with the following statement:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM tracking 
LEFT JOIN files ON tracking.track_id = files.track_id 
    WHERE (tracking.archived = '0' AND approved = '0') 
 ORDER BY tracking.po_number;
```

This however will return the same record 3 times to me.  I guess I need to add a unique clause somewhere, but every where I think it should go, gives me an SQL statement error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a inner join if you want to match only the ids that exist in both tables. To avoid duplicates, use distinct

```
 SELECT distinct [list of columns] 
 FROM tracking, files 
 WHERE tracking.track_id = files.track_id  AND 
       tracking.archived = '0' AND approved = '0'
 ORDER BY tracking.po_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    a.*
FROM      tracking a
JOIN      (
          SELECT   track_id
          FROM     files
          WHERE    approved = 0
          GROUP BY track_id
          ) b ON a.track_id = b.track_id
WHERE     a.archived = 0
ORDER BY  a.po_number
```